# codeigniter-data not retrieve from model

Tags: php, codeigniter, soap

I have successfully made a soap server using codeigniter. i want pass an array from model to controller. but i only get null. here my code:

Model:

```
       $this->db->select('player_item, count(*) as total');
       $this->db->from('rps'); 
       $this->db->group_by('player_item');
       $query = $this->db->get();
       $rows = array();
       foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
       {
          $rows[] = $row;

       }
      return $rows;
```

Soap server:

```
     function get_player(){
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->model("player");
        $data['player']=$CI->player ->get_player();
        return $data;
}
```

Soap client:

```
$result = $this->nusoap_client ->call('get_player');
print_r($result);
```

i don't know my code at server correct or not. i am just new to SOAP..

Comment: seems your query fine.Try to echo out `$this->db->last_query()` and check what query it produces

Comment: `print_r($rows)` check are you getting value within

Answer (score 0):

```
try to write below of this line
$data['player']=$CI->player ->get_player();
echo '<pre>'; 
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>'; 
die;
```

and check weather you are getting data or not .if you are not getting data then var_dump($this->db->last_query());

and you can also check in model that you are getting data from database or not.

```
       $this->db->select('player_item, count(*) as total');
       $this->db->from('rps'); 
       $this->db->group_by('player_item');
       $query = $this->db->get();
       $rows = array();
       foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
       {
          $rows[] = $row;

       }


echo '<pre>'; 
print_r($rows);
echo '</pre>'; 
die;

      return $rows;
```

Comment: it does getting data. but when it pass to client side then return to null value.

Comment: can you show me your client side code so I will check what's the error is there?

Comment: what are you passing in $this->nusop_client->call('')?  try this $result = $this->nusoap_client ->call('player');
print_r($result);

Comment: what are you passing in this function $this->nusop_client->call('here')?

Comment: nusoap_client ($endpoint, $wsdl=false, $proxyhost=false, $proxyport=false, $proxyusername=false, $proxypassword=false, $timeout=0, $response_timeout=30, $portName= '')

Comment: call ($operation, $params=array(), $namespace='http://tempuri.org', $soapAction='', $headers=false, $rpcParams=null, $style='rpc', $use='encoded')

Comment: call_user_func(array('MyClass', 'myCallbackMethod')); $result = $this->nusoap_client ->call_user_func(array('MyClass','mycallbackMethod')); print_r($result);

Answer (score 0):

Add second parameter in `select('fields', false)` function `false` to skip automatic apostrophe on fields, CI automatic add apostrophe on mysql query fields, so when you use mysql function like `count(*)` then it will give you mysql error, your query will look like

```
SELECT `player_item`, `count(*)` as `total` ......
```

changes

```
$this->db->select('player_item, count(*) as total');
```

to

```
 $this->db->select('`player_item`, count(*) as `total`', false);
```